# Visual Studio DateTime format in context menu

Tags: visual-studio, datetime-format

Pretty specific question, I guess, but is there a way to set the culture for the `DateTime` formatting in Visual Studio? My specific issue is that I do not live in one of the four countries that actually use PM/AM, so I can't ever remember which is which. Frankly, I don't care to either. Image here to show what I mean:

[image]

I just want the formatting to be a sensible 24-hour format instead. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048373/visual-studio-change-date-time-format

Comment: @RemyBaas My region in Windows is already set correctly. However, printing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` says `en-US`.